# Trouble with the new PnP.PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, pnp.powershell

Using the SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline module, to upload a file, to a specific folder (in a specific site), I used to run commands like this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://<company>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site name>" -Credentials $cred -ErrorAction Stop
$memStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(($data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation)))
Add-PnPFile -FileName $fileName -Folder "/Shared Documents/<folder>/<sub folder>" -Stream $memStream -ErrorAction Stop
```

Since SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline is being replaced by PnP.PowerShell, I tried running the same command in with the new module installed. After adding the required consent (Register-PnPManagementShellAccess), I got the error:

> Connect-PnPOnline : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I changed the connect command to:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://<company>.sharepoint.com/" -Credentials $cred -ErrorAction Stop
```

That seemed to work:

> VERBOSE: Acquiring token

> VERBOSE: Token acquired VERBOSE: PnP

> PowerShell Cmdlets (1.10.0.0)

When I ran the Add-PnPFile command again, there were no errors, but I cannot find the file in SharePoint. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multi-factor authentication enabled on the account? If yes, please try to use `-UseWebLogin` switch parameter ,the connect command:

```
Connect-PnpOnline -Url https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx -UseWebLogin
```

My test script and results(upload a file to a specific folder):

```
Connect-PnpOnline -Url https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx -UseWebLogin 
$localpath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\upload.txt"  
$splib = "test_library\test"  
Add-PnPFile -Path $localPath -Folder $splib
```

[image]

[image]